# How to add Facebook 'Like' button on each article on a Joomla website?

Tags: facebook, button, joomla, facebook-like

I want to add Facebook's new 'Like' button on the articles on my Joomla website. When I tried, I could add the button for my website, but not for individual articles.

How can I achieve the integration with an individual article? 
The end result should look something like http://mashable.com where 'Like' button appears on each article.

Answer (score 3):

**[See this please.](http://www.vergegraphics.com/blog/joomla/77-facebook-like-button-module)**

OR

**[Facebook Like Button](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/facebook-display/12376?qh=YToxMjp7aTowO3M6ODoiZmFjZWJvb2siO2k6MTtzOjQ6Imxpa2UiO2k6MjtzOjY6Imxpa2VseSI7aTozO3M6NjoibGlraW5nIjtpOjQ7czo1OiJsaWtlZCI7aTo1O3M6NToibGlrZXMiO2k6NjtzOjc6Imxpa2luZ3MiO2k6NztzOjY6ImJ1dHRvbiI7aTo4O3M6NzoiYnV0dG9ucyI7aTo5O3M6MTM6ImZhY2Vib29rIGxpa2UiO2k6MTA7czoyMDoiZmFjZWJvb2sgbGlrZSBidXR0b24iO2k6MTE7czoxMToibGlrZSBidXR0b24iO30%3D)**

Comment: the links are outdated/dead

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spearhead Facebook like button module. It is very simple to use and it served my purpose, it has added language support for many languages including German, Spanish, Hungarian, Italian etc....

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/republish/14580

You can also download its source from the Google code page.

http://code.google.com/p/joomla-facebook-like-button-module/

Just install the module and select the position in your Joomla administration backend.